# C++20 concept that supposedly depends on itself

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

In my world, a `StrictNodeType` should be anything that defines the types `PredContainer` and `SuccContainer`, so I wrote

```
  template<typename N>
  concept StrictNodeType = requires {
    typename N::PredContainer;
    typename N::SuccContainer;
  };
```

However, GCC-11.2 gives me the following error:

```
error: satisfaction of atomic constraint 'requires{typename N::PredContainer;typename N::SuccContainer;} [with N = typename std::remove_cvref<_Tp>::type::Node]' depends on itself
  164 |   concept StrictNodeType = requires {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~
  165 |     typename N::PredContainer;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  166 |     typename N::SuccContainer;something;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  167 | };
```

How is that possible? Why can't GCC simply inspect the given type and check if it provides the requested subtypes?

Here's a minimum breaking example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename N>
concept StrictNodeType = requires {
    typename N::something;
};

template<StrictNodeType N> using Int = int; 

template<int>
struct X {using type = Int<X>; };

using ThisBreaks = Int<X<0>>;
```

Comment: Without a minimal example, the question is almost useless as it is hard to guess the code you didn't provide.

Comment: GCC 11.2 [compiles this code without error](https://godbolt.org/z/9e5E5WEcc).  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mre]?

Comment: well, what I mean is, there should not be **any code** that produces this error since, no matter the rest of the code, `StrictNodeType` does **not** depend on itself.

Comment: @igel: "*no matter the rest of the code*" Clearly it does matter, since you're the only one getting the error.

Comment: A part of the error got cut off. Also, even if not for this error, the code would still be invalid, because the concept wouldn't be satisfied.

Comment: I think I got now what @NicolBolas means. While `StrictNodeType` does not depend on itself, `StrictNodeType<N>` may very well depend on itself - namely if `N`  depends on `StrictNodeType`. I guess this is the case here, even tho, in theory, a compiler could still check `StrictNodeType<N>` without fully instanciating `N`...

Comment: "in theory, a compiler could still check StrictNodeType<N> without fully instanciating N" This is not how C++ templates work. They are only checked on instantiation, as required by the standard.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is an infinite recursion issue that constrains a concept more than it would be without it. I made a few changes to get more directly at the issue:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename N>
concept StrictNodeType = requires {
    typename N::something;
};

#if 1
template<StrictNodeType N> using Int = int; 
#else
template<typename N> using Int = int; 
#endif

template<int>
struct X { using something = Int<X<0>>; };

using ThisBreaks=Int<X<0>>;

ThisBreaks foo()
{
    return ThisBreaks{};
}
```

This yields the following error:

```
<source>:15:37: error: template constraint failure for 'template<class N>  requires  StrictNodeType<N> using Int = int'
   15 | struct X { using something = Int<X<0>>; };
      |                                     ^~
<source>:15:37: note: constraints not satisfied
<source>: In substitution of 'template<class N>  requires  StrictNodeType<N> using Int = int [with N = X<0>]':
<source>:15:37:   required from here
<source>:4:9:   required for the satisfaction of 'StrictNodeType<N>' [with N = X<0>]
<source>:4:26:   in requirements  [with N = X<0>]
<source>:5:14: note: the required type 'typename N::something' is invalid
    5 |     typename N::something;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: note: set '-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=' to at least 2 for more detail
<source>:17:25: error: template constraint failure for 'template<class N>  requires  StrictNodeType<N> using Int = int'
   17 | using ThisBreaks=Int<X<0>>;
      |                         ^~
<source>:17:25: note: constraints not satisfied
<source>: In substitution of 'template<class N>  requires  StrictNodeType<N> using Int = int [with N = X<0>]':
<source>:17:25:   required from here
<source>:4:9:   required for the satisfaction of 'StrictNodeType<N>' [with N = X<0>]
<source>:4:26:   in requirements  [with N = X<0>]
<source>:5:14: note: the required type 'typename N::something' is invalid
    5 |     typename N::something;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:19:1: error: 'ThisBreaks' does not name a type
   19 | ThisBreaks foo()
      | ^~~~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

Changing `#if 1` to `#if 0` compiles fine, only the Concept objects to the infinite recursion.

(Play with it here: https://godbolt.org/z/56Yd7W3sf )

Comment: this is also odd - if we add `-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=200` then the error is `<source>:5:14: error: no type named 'something' in 'struct X<0>'` which seems to contradict the code. But I guess one has to get that this is the relevant error: `<source>:5:14: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct X<0>'`

Comment: @igel By setting depth=200, it as if anything depth of 201 or more doesn't exist. so there is no type X<201> as reported.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, I'm unable to find anything about X<201> in the error message oO

Comment: X<20> means X<0> as level 201 of recursion, you told the compiler to go no deeper, so anything that would have been created simply does not exist. Look at : https://godbolt.org/z/oqhrjKcvf : 
```
template <int X> struct UP {
    UP() {UP<X+1> x;}
};

template <> struct UP<202> {
};

UP<0> x;
```
And I have set -ftemplate-depth=200 so it fails to find UP<202> that will stop the recursion. As far as the compiler is concerned, UP<202> at depth 200 does not exist.

Comment: OK but I was talking about `-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=200` not `-ftemplate-depth=200`. I suppose I get the idea of finite template depth recursion, although I still find the error message `no type named 'something' in 'struct X<0>` confusing and would have rather seen `template instantiation depth exceeds maximum` like in your godbolt.